# Isn't that the point of school, that between 8 and 3 he's your problem

Tags: grammaticality

I would appreciate it if anyone can comment on my analysis of the sentence, "Isn't that the point of school, that between 8 and 3 he's your problem."

This is the basic form of the sentence: "That is the point of school  that he is your problem" = That (extraposed subject)  +  is ( verb ) + the point of school (complement)   + that he is your problem" (noun clause as complement) .
This can be rewritten as an interrogative: "Isn't that the point of school that between 8 and 3 he's your problem?"

The first "that" functions in the same way as "it" (a 'dummy' subject)  in a sentence like "It is obvious that he has a problem."

Thanks.

Comment: You first "that" is redundant. IMHO, it's probably not even *grammatical* unless we assume it refers to some previously-mentioned point/rule/practice, rather than "forward referencing" the following "that-clause" which already includes its own copy of the word. If you *must* keep the first instance, I'd replace the comma by an em-dash or semicolon and *remove the second instance*..

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the first *that* is certainly grammatical: that's the point of the sentence(!) Removing it is possible, but would change the meaning.

Comment: @TimLymington: As I said, it seems to me OP's exact text couldn't be the *first* utterance in a conversation, because the first "that" should refer *back* to something already referenced. Obviously that issue doesn't arise if the conversation has already established that "responsibility for the child" is the current topic. I don't see any possibility of different *meanings* dependent on whether the first "that" is present or not - it's just a matter of whether it's *appropriate* or not (i.e. - has that "topic" already been introduced into the conversation).

Comment: I would turn this into a statement as follows: *The point of school is that between 8 and 3 he's your problem.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that the first 'that' must refer back to something already referenced - and I assume it does.  But, that being the case, the second clause, "that between 8 and 3 he's your problem" summarises the previously referenced statement.

Comment: The OP’s addition of a question mark is correct  - the syntax precludes any possibility other than an interrogative.  There must, however, be some from of punctuation mark to separate the two clauses (i.e. between ‘school’ and ‘that’).  To me, it reads perfectly well with a comma in that position – although perhaps grammarians would insist on something else.  (An em-dash, to me, represents a longer pause or marks a clause that adds additional but inessential information – as demonstrated in the previous sentence and the present one.)

Answer (score 1):

The two instances of "that", one per phrase, are needed to give the whole question a rhetorical shading. The speaker is essentially *asserting* that "between 8 and 3 he's your problem", and then asking for confirmation that the listener agrees.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think your analysis is accurate. What makes the sentence seem odd visually (but not aurally) is that omits several words that would explicitly link the first *that* to the phrase beginning with the second *that*. If we set up the speaker's thought as a dialogue, it might run as follows:

> ***Speaker A:*** Isn't that the point of school?
>
> ***Speaker B:*** What do you mean by "that"?
>
> ***Speaker A:*** The fact that between 8 and 3 he's your problem.

But instead of expressing the underlying idea in pieces in dialogue form, Speaker A (or the writer) compresses the original idea and the clarification into a single sentence. In writing, we might want to express the clarification in more words and in somewhat different order:

> Isn't that fundamental shift in authority and responsibility—the fact that between 8 and 3, for all practical purposes, he's your problem—the point of school?

But the same core idea is present in the compressed form, which is truer to the way people actually speak in informal settings. The only thing I would be inclined to change is the punctuation. Whether the sentence is intended as a question or as an assertion, I would end it with a question mark and I would use an em dash rather than a comma to indicate the interruption/clarification that arises with the introduction of the phrase "that between 8 and 3 he's you problem." Thus:

> Isn't that the point of school—that between 8 and 3 he's your problem?

This sentence sentence seems to me to be completely normal, understandable, and grammatical in spoken English. We make sense of similarly constructed statements every day in conversation. But when we write them down, we forgo the the benefits of multiple crucial vocal cues—changes in tempo, pitch, intonation, and inflection that guide a hearer's understanding of a speaker's meaning. The trick to overcoming this loss is to punctuate the sentence in a way that provides the best visual substitute for the lost vocal guidance.